# overridePendingTransition makes screen black in API 23,but working well in API 29

Tags: android, overridependingtransition

In my app,i added an refresh button to reload the activity.I also uses overridePendingOperation for smoother transition.

This is the method,which is reloading the activity.

```
private void refreshActivity(){
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,R.anim.slide_up);
    startActivity(getIntent());
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,R.anim.slide_up);
}
```

This method works perfectly in my RealmeC2(API 29) device,but not working on Xiaomi 4(API 23).It's just showing black screen when i press refresh button.I have no idea why it is happening?

Can anybody help me please?

I am 100% sure that in both devices animation-transition's scale set to 1x.